# PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object line 638

Tags: php, wordpress

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/admin/data/www/test.com/wp-content/themes/bd/inc/blt-functions.php on line 638

```
       if(!function_exists('blt_get_comment')){
            function blt_get_comment($comment, $args, $depth){

 (LINE 638)     $author_comment_id = get_user_by('email', get_comment_author_email())->ID; 
                $comment_score = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'blt_score', true );
                if(empty($comment_score)){
                    $comment_score = 0;
                }
```

Comment: `->ID` thats the point where the error comes from, so `get_user_by` does not return what is expected

Comment: how i can fix this error?

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with wordpress, but show the results of `var_dump(get_comment_author_email();`

Comment: Error tells you everything : get_user_by does not return a WP_User. What does get_comment_author_email() return? If it is an email address, does it exist in WP users? If no, dont fetch the ->ID.

Comment: string(20) "info@test.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means, `get_user_by` is returning `FALSE`, meaning user couldn't be found. You need to do a check, like so:

```
 $user = get_user_by('email', get_comment_author_email());
 $author_comment_id = (($user != FALSE) ? $user->ID : 0);
 //or a check like this
 if(!$user)
 {
     return false;
 }
```

Note, it might be a good idea to check later on, if `$author_comment_id` is not 0

Comment: Спасибо, решение помогло! Tnx